# node-sass watcher gives undefined variable error

Tags: sass, node-sass

main.scss

```
@import "sass1";
@import "sass2";
```

sass1.scss

```
$white-color: white
```

sass2.scss

```
.body{ color: $white-color}
```

If I just compile one time like this, it works fine

```
node-sass main.scss main.css
```

But if I use the watcher like this, modify and save _sass2.css gives me error

```
node-sass --watch main.css main.css
```

{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "sass2.scss",
  "line": 3,
  "column": 11,
  "message": "Undefined variable: \"$whites\".",
  "formatted": "Error: Undefined variable: \"$whites\".\n        on line 3 of sass2.scss\n>>     color:$whites;\n   ----------^\n"
}

I have tried to use "sass" instead of "node-sass" and it works, is it a bug of node-sass?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out the problem is the file name of the partials.
We should name files with underscore prefix if we do not want it to generate its own css code.

Then the solution is to change

> sass2.scss

to

> _sass2.scss

. (Also change sass1.scss to _sass1.scss although it is not the problem of the error)